# How to redirect desktop page to mobile page using ExternalContext

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, primefaces-mobile, externalcontext

Project structure:

```
root
 -WebContent
    -mobile
      -login.xhtml
    -desktop
      -login.xhtml
```

My web.xml will load desktop/login.xhtml onload which uses UserBean as a backing bean, In postconstruct of UserBean, I'm trying to redirect my login to mobile/login.xhtml if the renderkit is mobile. I'm doing this by the following code:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void myPostConstruct(){
        String renderKitId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getRenderKitId();        
        if(renderKitId.equalsIgnoreCase("PRIMEFACES_MOBILE")){
            try
            {

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/mobile/login.xhtml");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm confused with the absolute path to be given for redirect; I need to move from desktop/login.xhtml to mobile/login.xhtml; how do I do that?

Comment: have you tried with "~/mobile/login.xhtml" ?

Comment: yup! not working. The resulting url is : "localhost:8080/desktop/~/mobile/login.xhtml"

Comment: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContextName() this returns "root" which is correct!

Comment: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler()
     .handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "MOBILE", "/mobile/login.xhtml"); This solved my issue. Thank you!